# my lightbox plugin is flashing in full screen?

Tags: css, prettyphoto

something is going on. everytime I click on it and view it to full screen it flashes 5 seconds later then starts flashing every 2 seconds?
http://icpy.webs.com/prettyPhoto/index.html#prettyPhoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lightbox is in slideshow mode with autostart true, change to false will solve the problem.

```
$(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: false});
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not want to use slideshow can simply change the line in question to:

```
$(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much this helps A LOT! one quick question. Why is the button "close" not showing up? It's a black box.

Comment: The reference to the image is wrong. Is currently pointing to "http://static.websimages.com/Images/imageNotFound.gif" try putting/create a folder "images" and put images of lighbox inside.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is scrolling though the slides. the flashing is the animation

Comment: is there anything I can change throughout the code? I'm so new to jquery and yes I am stubborn to figure out jquery from the beginning (taking the shortcut).

Comment: You have a `div` like so `<div class="pp_fade" style="display: none;">` that is animating between between `display:block` and `display:none;` with an opacity fade. There maybe an option within your plugin to control this